# Can the Trello Android app support multiple Google accounts?

Tags: trello, google-account, android

I have two Google accounts (for work and personal).

This works fine in Chrome, but is there an easy way in the Android app to switch accounts?

Comment: You should up vote this feature https://trello.com/c/dUtbLJux/290-support-for-multiple-accounts

Comment: Unfortunately that feature request was put on a "Future ideas" list then the entire list was archived. More votes wouldn't hurt but it looks like Trello aren't interested. On some phones there are workarounds allowing you to have two instances of the same app (e.g. Samsung "Secure folder"), so you can log into a different user on each

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about using a web application (it belongs to [android.se])

Answer (score 4):

Log out, then back in.  Not easy but not hard either.

From any Android Trello tab select Settings then Logout from there.  Now log in with your other Google Account.

Comment: Not effective, since **notifications** will not work on any account except the last one used.